# Getting the ID,using a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to change some php/mysql code from 2008 so that it uses current standards. I'm fairly new to php/mysql so I'm struggling, despite doing plenty of research.

```
$sql_email_check = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? LIMIT 1");
$sql_email_check->bind_param('i', $email);
$sql_email_check->execute();

echo "<pre>".   print_r($sql_email_check, true)."<-- sql email check</pre>";
```

I'm trying to grab the ID so that I can use it at a later time, in my code.

My question is (I'm so confused, maybe I'm asking the wrong question), how do I display/grab the ID? 
I'm new to this so if I'm doing something, code wise, that isn't up to standards, please let me know.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php and/or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: If your query is good and you do have data in your `email` column, try adding this `while($row = $sql_email_check->fetch_assoc()) { $row['email']; }` after `$sql_email_check->execute();` (this would be for your `display` question) - You need to loop through in order to show/echo your record(s).

Comment: `$sql_email_check->bind_param('i', $email);`  Is `$email` really an int?  Or should that actually be `$sql_email_check->bind_param('s', $email);`?

Comment: You've got a point there @RocketHazmat

Comment: good eye. email is a string. Changing that doesn't fix my issue, however. Am I doing something wrong with the print_r() statement? nothing gets printed...

Comment: Did you not try my suggestion in [`this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437144/getting-the-id-using-a-prepared-statement#comment32344339_21437144) @user3115806

Comment: yes @Fred-ii- . I get a fatal error from the first bit of your code...  call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()

Comment: You'll need to post your full code. It could be a number of things. And did you change the `i` to `s` in `$sql_email_check->bind_param('i', $email);` as in `$sql_email_check->bind_param('s', $email);`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql_email_check = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? LIMIT 1");
$sql_email_check->bind_param('i', $email);
$sql_email_check->execute();
$sec = sql_email_check->get_result();
$row = $sec->fetch_assoc();

$id = $row['id'];    

echo $id;
```